# S3 dynamic cognito permissions on object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Ok, I’m starting to go crazy here. I have a web application where users log in with their Cognito user accounts. The users can create case-items which consist of a lot of different information. Only the creator of the case-item and admins (a special Cognito group) is able to see the case-item. I solve this with a secured API Gateway which is connected to Lambda functions where I can use the Cognito ID Token to get what I want.

Now I want to be able to add attachments/files to these case-items but I have **NO IDEA** how to solve the permission problem.

**How should I upload a file/object to the S3 Bucket and set permission on it on-the-fly???**

The first approach was to upload files as binary data through the API Gateway which was connected to a Lambda function. But what to do from there? I wanted to use the JavaScript SDK for S3 and found methods like `S3.putObject`, `S3.upload` and `S3.putObjectAcl` but it doesn’t really help since I can’t find a way to use Cognito accounts.

Another approach is to upload files to S3 directly from the browser so I started to read up about that. Found out that you can create a pre-signed url (like here: https://sanderknape.com/2017/08/using-pre-signed-urls-upload-file-private-s3-bucket/) but it still doesn’t help me to put right permissions on the objects.

Now I'm thinking of storing some sort of ACL in my own DynamoDB to keep track of S3 object permissions but this feels sooooo wrong. Must be a better way?

So I’m stuck. This is my first project working with AWS so I might be missing something really basic here. Should I approach this in an entire different way?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

How should I upload a file/object to the S3 Bucket and set permission on it on-the-fly???

I am interpreting this as to say that you want each Cognito user to only access their own S3 "folder" and upload or access files in it.

Just a question is their any reason for using API Gateway? I see that you are uploading images - API Gateway has a 10mb limit - so you will be limited on the images that you can supply.

You are passing the id token via either a custom authorizer or a userpool authorizer. Either way make sure that you pass the entire event to the Lambda function in your integration response so that you have the id token available in the event object.

Now that id token is available in your Lambda function.

Question: What is the IAM Role that is associated with the Cognito User group?

Please forward it.

What the access permissions come down to is the associated Trust relationship for the IAM Role as well the IAM Role variables. In the IAM you have to make use of Policy variables such that those who assume the role have access to the S3 bucket based their identityid(not idtoken an idtoken = userpool).

And this is where the first issue comes in.

see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/

The way you are doing things is different in that you are making use of Cognito Usergroups - the usual way this is done is by using a Userpool as an authentication provider for an identity pool and then making use of policy variables in the IAM role of the Authenticated role of the identity pool.

Aside from the above the second issue is that you are using Cognito UserPools with Usergroups and you are doing the authentication on the client but then you want to make a request to S3 from a Lambda function.

How is the Lambda function suppose to get the AWS keys that are residing on the client?

Even though the idtoken is available in your Lambda function, the Lambda function does not have the temporary AWS keys cached. And this is where I believe you will run into an unauthorized error.

So to help me troubleshoot - please forward:

1. The IAM role for the Cognito Usergroup
2. The Trust Relationship for that IAM role
3. An id token for a user (I want to have a look at the claims in the token)

You have an interesting use case - forward the information - I can have a look. Basically you want to apply the solution using only Cognito Userpool with Usergroups - this can be a valid use case.

Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Q: "I am interpreting this as to say that you want each Cognito user to only access their own S3 "folder" and upload or access files in it."
A: No, as I wrote files should be connected to "case-items". These cases can only be reached by the creator of the case or admins. 

Q: "Just a question is their any reason for using API Gateway?"
A: It's a web application so I think it's quite natural to use an API for it. If you ask why I use it for files - I'm not. That is only one of the things I have tried. And that is why I'm here asking what is the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: So lets sum it up again. 

I already have a functional web application using lambda, api gateway, dynamodb, cognito with user pool etc. My question is ONLY how I should handle files and the best way to solve my problem. I'm open to all suggestions!